# $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R},m=\frac{a+b}{2}$, then $f(a)+f(b) = \frac{2}{b-a}\int_a^b[f(x)+(x-m)f'(x)]\ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ with the derivative of $f$ being integrable, and$m=\frac{a+b}{2}$, then prove that

$$f(a)+f(b) = \frac{2}{b-a}\int_a^b[f(x)+(x-m)f'(x)]\ dx$$

Well, this one is tricky, how am I supposed to even begin this??? I truly have no idea.

Comment: Try integrating by parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the product rule

$$f(x) + (x - m)f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}[(x - m)f(x)].$$

Thus

$$\int_a^b [f(x) + (x - m)f'(x)]\, dx = (x - m)f(x)\bigg|_{x = a}^b = \cdots$$

Complete the argument.